# Raspberry Pi Johnny-five.io and GPIO pins

Tags: raspbian, gpio, node.js, javascript

My code looks quite similar to this:

```
board.on('ready', () => {
   const motor = new five.Motor('GPIO17');
   motor.start(255);
}
```

The problem is that when I run the code, its gets error: Unknown pin "undefined". When I hook my motor up to GPIO18 it works fine but I doesn't want to let GPIO 17 work. I am aware of the different GPIO numbering such was Physical and wiringPi and BCM however any numbering of GPIO 17 gets this error. Help please

Comment: So for WiringPi GPIO numbering pin 1 works fine but when I use 0 i get error unknown in undefined

Comment: Ive been testing out all the pins. It appears to be just Wiring Pi pin 0 that is getting the error. Wiring Pi pins: 1,23,24,25 and other pins work. Pin 2 says does not support mode pwm...ok makes since but whats wrong with pin 0?

Comment: Im guessing its a JohnnyFive error. I installed onoff npm package and GPIO 17 works just fine

Answer (score 0):

Johnny Five  does not support use of GPIO17 for motor usage.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.